# Replacing analyze-string with a new one when it cannot be matched

Tags: regex, xslt, pattern-matching, xslt-2.0

I am using the following piece of code to parse a string of text and identify substrings that match the regex pattern = `'AND facet_(.*?):\(("?.*?"?)\)'`

```
<xsl:template name="facets">
                <xsl:param name="q" />
                <xsl:analyze-string select="$q" regex='AND facet_(.*?):\(("?.*?"?)\)'>
                        <xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="regex-group(1) = 'example1'">
                                    <facet name="domain"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)" /></facet>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="regex-group(1) = 'example2'">
                                    <facet name="content_type_norm"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)" /></facet>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="regex-group(1) = 'example2'">
                                    <facet name="sentiment"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)" /></facet>
                                </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:matching-substring>
                       <xsl:non-matching-substring></xsl:non-matching-substring>
                </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>
```

In case the regex is not matched, I would like to replace it with 'AND NOT facet_(.*?):(("?.*?"?))' and keep the same conditions from the regex-group(). However I am not sure how this can fit with the current piece of code.

I have tried something like:

```
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
     <xsl:value-of select="replace(., 'AND NOT facet_(.*?):\(("?.*?"?)\)')>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
```

but it did not seem to work. Can you help?

Comment: The `replace` function takes three or four arguments, it is not clear what you want to be the replacement as I don't see a third argument. If all you need to know is escaping the quote characters then use `&quot;`: `<xsl:value-of select="replace(., 'AND NOT facet_(.*?):\((&quot;?.*?&quot;?)\)', 'put replacement here')">`

Comment: perhaps you can add another analyze-string in the non-matching-substring?

Comment: @MartinHonnen, you are right, I have missed the 3rd argument. Thanks!

Comment: @JoelM.Lamsen I was not sure that was actually allowed. Thanks!