# Including analyze-string in a non-matching-substring - XSLT 2.0

Tags: regex, xslt, solr, xslt-2.0

As suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835071/replacing-analyze-string-with-a-new-one-when-it-cannot-be-matched), it seems to be possible to include `<xsl:analyze-string>` in a `<xsl:non-matching-substring>`. In my case, I have two regex `'AND facet_(.*?):\(("?.*?"?)\)'` and `'AND NOT facet_(.*?):\(("?.*?"?)\)'`, which are used to construct two different Solr faceting requests to be consumed by my web application, the latter being by exclusion (AND NOT).

This is my XML:

```
   <facets>
      <facet name="domain">
        <facetEntry count="8007">domain1.co.uk</facetEntry>
        <facetEntry count="6497">domain2.co.uk</facetEntry>
        <facetEntry count="6180">domain3.co.uk</facetEntry>            
      </facet>
   <facets>
```

Whereas, this is the template I am using:

```
<xsl:template name="facets">
                <xsl:param name="q" />
                <xsl:analyze-string select="$q" regex='AND facet_(.*?):\(("?.*?"?)\)'>
                        <xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="regex-group(1) = 'example1'">
                                    <facet name="domain"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)" /></facet>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="regex-group(1) = 'example2'">
                                    <facet name="content_type_norm"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)" /></facet>
                                </xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="regex-group(1) = 'example2'">
                                    <facet name="sentiment"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)" /></facet>
                                </xsl:when>
                        </xsl:choose>
                        </xsl:matching-substring>
                       <xsl:non-matching-substring></xsl:non-matching-substring>
                </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>
```

I have made several attempts to include an extra `<xsl:analyze-string>` inside , but I am always returned with a syntax error. For example:

```
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
                           <xsl:analyze-string select="$q" regex='AND NOT facet_(.*?):\(("?.*?"?)\)'>
<xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="regex-group(1) = 'example1'">
                                        <facet name="domain"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)" /></facet>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="regex-group(1) = 'example2'">
                                        <facet name="content_type_norm"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)" /></facet>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="regex-group(1) = 'example2'">
                                        <facet name="sentiment"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)" /></facet>
                                    </xsl:when>
                            </xsl:choose>
                         </xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    </xsl:analyze-string>
```

In that case I am returned with the following error:

> The element type "xsl:analyze-string" must be terminated by the
>   matching end-tag "".

I am rather stuck and I am not sure whether this is really allowed in XSLT. Can you help?

Thanks indeed,

I.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can nest a second `xsl:analyze-string` into the `xsl:non-matching-substring` if you want but of course the content of any `xsl:analyze-string` has to follow the rules

> The content of the xsl:analyze-string instruction must take one of the
>   following forms:
>
> ```
> A single xsl:matching-substring instruction, followed by zero or more xsl:fallback instructions
>
> A single xsl:non-matching-substring instruction, followed by zero or more xsl:fallback instructions
>
> A single xsl:matching-substring instruction, followed by a single xsl:non-matching-substring instruction, followed by zero or more
> ```
>
> xsl:fallback instructions
>
> [ERR XTSE1130] It is a static error if the xsl:analyze-string
>   instruction contains neither an xsl:matching-substring nor an
>   xsl:non-matching-substring element.

So don't put an `xsl:choose` inside of it directly, rather `xsl:matching-substring` and/or `xsl:non-matching-substring`, which can then take any sequence constructor if needed, which allows `xsl:choose` of course.

Here is a complete example that is well-formed XML and syntactically correct XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:template name="facets">
  <xsl:param name="q" />
  <xsl:analyze-string select="$q" regex='AND facet_(.*?):\(("?.*?"?)\)'>
    <xsl:matching-substring>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="regex-group(1) = 'example1'">
          <facet name="domain"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)" /></facet>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="regex-group(1) = 'example2'">
          <facet name="content_type_norm"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)" /></facet>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="regex-group(1) = 'example2'">
          <facet name="sentiment"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)" /></facet>
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>                                                    
      <xsl:analyze-string select="$q" regex='AND NOT facet_(.*?):\(("?.*?"?)\)'>
        <xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="regex-group(1) = 'example1'">
              <facet name="domain"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)" /></facet>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="regex-group(1) = 'example2'">
              <facet name="content_type_norm"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)" /></facet>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="regex-group(1) = 'example2'">
              <facet name="sentiment"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)" /></facet>
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
  </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Try to use an XML editor or editor plugin, it helps getting the proper nesting, and tag completion should avoid errors with typos like `</xsl:matching-sustring>`.

Comment: I have posted a syntactically correct sample which hopefully helps finding the right XML and XSLT syntax. Please put any code samples in your question, not in answers. And consider using an XML editor to help you with the right syntax.

Comment: Also note that I have made no attempt in this answer to implement a certain matching, I have simply put the right syntax in place. I am not sure you even need a nested analyze-string, as normally I would expect it doing `<xsl:non-matching-substring><xsl:analyze-string select="." ...` instead of `<xsl:non-matching-substring><xsl:analyze-string select="$q" ...`.

Comment: thank you so much. I have spotted the typo almost straightaway, but I was definitively wrong on where closing the nested  analyze-string. Thanks indeed!

Answer (score 2):

Before you can write XSLT, you have to learn how to write XML. A start tag named xsl:analyze-string can't be matched by an end tag named xsl:choose.